# Template Functions Referring to Globals (Depending on Type)

Tags: c++, templates, stl

For many classes in my codebase, I need to maintain a global map allowing me to look up instances of that class. 
Example:

```
// In ExampleClass.h

ExampleClass *getExampleClass(std::string name);
std::unordered_map<std::string, ExampleClass *> &getAllExampleClasses();
bool addExampleClass(std::string name, ExampleClass *e);


// In ExampleClass.cpp

std::unordered_map<std::string, ExampleClass *> exampleClasses;
ExampleClass *getExampleClass(std::string name) {
   return exampleClasses.find(name) == exampleClasses.end() ? nullptr : exampleClasses.find(name)->second;
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, ExampleClass *> &getAllExampleClasses() {
   return &exampleClasses;
}

bool addExampleClass(std::string name, ExampleClass *e) {
   if (exampleClasses.find(name) == exampleClasses.end()) {
       exampleClasses[name] = e;
       return true;
   }
   else
       return false;
}
```

After doing this for several classes, I decided to put all of these global variables and methods in global.cpp/h and use template functions.

```
template <class T> T *get(std::string name);
template <class T> std::unordered_map<std::string, T *> &getAll();
template <class T> bool add(std::string name, T *);
```

*Is there a way in the template function definition to specify which global map to lookup based on the type? So that get("name") will know to check the exampleClasses map?*

Comment: Actually, the workerThread can be templated too and added to the globals.cpp/h. And remove the need for a getAll function. This also makes building much easier (since global.h does not not need to include any class headers, only global.cpp where the global maps are defined does.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions in your question, I will address the first. What you likely want is to group all of your functions as `static`s in a single class template. Note that your implementations of your functions are very inefficient, so I've fixed that for you too:

```
template <typename T>
using RegistryMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, T*>;

template <typename T>
class Registry {
    static RegistryMap<T> registry;

public:
    static T* get(const std::string& name) {
        auto it = registry.find(name);
        return it == registry.end() ? nullptr : it->second;
    }

    static const RegistryMap<T>& getAll() {
        return registry;
    }

    static bool add(const std::string& name, T* object) {
        T*& store = registry[name];
        if (store) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            store = object;
            return true;
        }
    }
};

template <typename T>
RegistryMap<T> Registry<T>::registry;
```

For your original example, you would this as:

```
Registry<Example>::get("name", &some_example);
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it be better to post as two questions, so I can mark this as accepted? Appreciate the improved implementations.

Comment: @user2411693 Always one question per question.